# how to send data securely from one page to another page using php

Tags: php, encryption

First page is collecting the data from user. And then it sends data to another page to do another process. I am using OpenSSL certificate. But I want to send data using encryption method. I want to do the following:

1. Create a single string using data.
2. Encrypt that string using public key.(I can use my public key got by OpenSSL)
3. Sending encrypted string to another page.
4. Decrypt that using private key. (I can use my private key got by OpenSSL)
5. Extract the string to get the variable clearly.

How can I do that?

Comment: Use session variables.

Comment: Thanks. But I want to create a string or another format to keep all data in same one. And then send to another page( server) after encrypting that data format. Can i do that using session variables?

Comment: If you use session variables you don't need to encrypt in the first place. Everything is kept on the server, it never goes over the network.

Comment: I want to send it over network. Just trying to create a payment gateway. The data which are inserted on shopping website should send to payment gateway. Does work session variables for me?

Comment: Session variables are for pages on the same site. If you're sending to a different site put it in POST data and send it with `cURL`.